# Azure Storage Firewall and Virtual Networks - how to prevent unauthorized access

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

In Azure Storage there's a section called Firewalls and Virtual Networks. May I know if I can use it for the following usecase ?

1. I have a video uploaded to the blob, and I need only a set of selected users who has logged in to the application view my video.
2. My WebAPI application is hosted as a Azure WebApp. Can I use the IP address where the WebApp is hosted to create a rule in the Firewalls and Virtual network section below to only allow access to Storage if the user request the URL via the WebApp.(Let's say /viewVid/myvideo.mp4 )
3. In case if the User copies the URL of the Video (by inspecting the HTML code), and paste it on the browser will the user be able to view the video as the request is not coming via the WebApp ?

Note: Overall objective is to prevent a User from copying a URL (by inspecting the HTML code) and downloading or viewing the video.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firewalls and VNet NSG's will are network level restrictions so they will not give you the user-level restrictions you are looking for.  You can use them to limit your surface area but to implement what you are asking for, you need to implement authentication.

Azure Blob Storage supports Shared Key, Shared Access Signatures (SAS), Azure Active Directory (AAD), Active Directory Directory Services (ADDS) and Anonymous public access.  The most secure way is to implement AAD with user delegation.  If you are not able to store the users for this application in AAD then you should look at SAS.  SAS token can be time-bound and restricted to certain IP addresses.

Also, you should take a look at Azure Media Player.  Microsoft Azure Media Services (AMS) is an extensible cloud-based platform that enables developers to build scalable media management and delivery applications. Media Services is based on REST APIs that enable you to securely upload, store, encode, and package video or audio content for both on-demand and live streaming delivery to various clients (for example, TV, PC, and mobile devices).

Links
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/authorize-data-access
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-sas-overview
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/previous/media-services-content-protection-overview

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The only reason I am not using Azure Media Service is due to its cost.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more on content protection on media service. Does it prevent a user from R-Clicking the html to find the Video URL and then download the file ?

Comment: It will protect from right-clicking and getting a URL with access to the content but it is possible for an adversary to sniff traffic of a legitimate user and get the key if you us AES-128 clear-key for protection.  If you require higher levels of security, you can implement a 3rd party DRM solution like MS PlayReady, Apple FairPlay or Google Widevine.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/previous/media-services-content-protection-overview#aes-128-clear-key-vs-drm

Comment: Thank you. I am new to this. Can you point me to a tutorial or article about DRM. There aren't much out there. Or any tutorial that walkthrough the steps of implementing one.

Comment: Sure, we have a couple DRM tutorials both here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/drm-playready-license-template-concept

Comment: Is this a good alternative ? https://www.npmjs.com/package/rx-player

Answer (score 0):

I belieave that you can use [app service Vnet integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet#manage-vnet-integration) feature for your project to restricted network access to storage account.